# Postgres получения значения из SETOF

Tags: postgresql

подскажите пожалуйста, как в Postgres получить значения множества SETOF?

У меня есть функция, которая возвращает 5 строк, как мне из нее вытащить например 3ю строку?

Например в другой функции переменной мне надо присвоить значение из 3й строки моей функции

var := my_setof_func(arg); - вот как тут можно указать, что мне нужна 3я строка?

Делал offset + limit, но может есть что-то проще

Спасибо. PS в доке нет информации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотелось бы заметить, что задача взять одну строку результата функции по некому порядку довольно странная. Возможно, вам нужна другая функция.

Тем не менее, все актуальные версии postgresql поддерживают выражение `WITH ORDINALITY` для вызова функций. При использовании этого выражения к строкам результата функции будет добавлено дополнительное поле с номером строки результата.

```
select ... into ... 
from function() WITH ORDINALITY 
where ordinality = 3;
```

Comment: спасибо, просто в одном месте надо взять 3е значение, а так функция должна быть SETOF.